# how to show 24 hour server time php

Tags: javascript, php, time

I want to display the server time on my website written in php.

I am using these lines of code in my website to display the time

```
<p>Date/Time:  </p>

var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
```

but the time displayed is in 12 hour clock, i want the website to show 24 hour time.

Comment: JavaScript will show the client time, not server. Use PHP’s `date` if you want server time, the docs have all the format options available listed in a table

Comment: can you provide me the code for displaying the time on the page? i don't know any programming language

Comment: you mean, i have to change the line to document.getElementById("datetime").date.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {hour12: false});

Comment: i have no coding experience, so no idea what to do, could you guys please provide me the complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, if you want client side time, just set hour12: false e.g. dt.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {hour12: false});

So the code (JS) will be:

```
<div id=datetime style="width:100px;"></div>


<script>
var dt = new Date(); 

document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML=(dt.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {hour12: false}));
</script>
```

However, if you want server time, you need to use server side script, For example PHP

```
<?php
echo date("F j, Y, G:i:s");
?>
```

or , if you just want the time (in 24-hour format), then

```
<?php
echo date("G:i:s");
?>
```

Comment: But OP states in question wants server date/time.

Comment: this still does not work, it shows the local time in 24 hour, i want server time in 24 hour

Comment: See my amended answer